# Erro ao inicializar o Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou estudando Analise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas, e antes nas aulas de programação estava aprendendo a usar Java com Spring Boot. Uso Netbeans 8.2 com JDK 8u261 e tenho dois HDs, tento salvar todos os arquivos no D, não sei se é por esse motivo que tá dando problema. Agora que vou voltar com as aulas online por causa da pandemia resolvi revisar a matéria. Do nada ao só construir o projeto me aparece um monte de erros, consegui resolver dois pelo menos, mas estes dois não consigo nada. Espero que me ajudei por favor. Tentei tirar foto, mas não ficou boa e achei melhor copiar e colar o que me aparece no console. Por favor tentem me ajudar até essa semana já que semana que vem começam minhas aulas, obg.

```
cd C:\Users\Home\Downloads\osworks-api\osworks-api; "JAVA_HOME=D:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_261" cmd /c "\"\"D:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"D:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" clean install\""
Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.4.1/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.4.1.pom

The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
  
  The project com.algaworks.osworks:osworks-api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\Home\Downloads\osworks-api\osworks-api\pom.xml) has 1 error
    Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.4.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.4.1/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.4.1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
'cmd' nÆo ‚ reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa oper vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
```

Comment: bom dia, coloca seu pom.xml tbm!

Comment: Desenvolva no Spring Tool Suite, vai te ajudar mais e esses pequenos erros não irão acontecer.